# How to detect the WordPress customizer preview iframe's width?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Tried using `window.outerWidth` which works fine for browser resize and native iframes, however for some unknown reason doesn't work when the site loads through the iframe in WordPress customizer preview, especially if I choose tablet and mobile sizes.

Current code:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    if(window.outerWidth < 721) {
        // Code to execute when iframe's width is 720px or less
    }
});
```

Note: this code loads inside the theme.

[WordPress customizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8BPi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `window.innerWidth` instead. So you will have the size of the iframe itself, instead of main window width.

Comment: I didn't expected `window.innerWidth` to work for this case scenario. Thanks @andergmartins! It was very helpful.